# What is the name of this symbol and what is the command to display it in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

Below is an image that I took of a symbol in "Logic for Philosophy" by Theodore Sider. The symbol is used to represent a function whose domain is Sentence letters of propositional logic and whose range is the set `{0,1}` (Called a PL-Interpretation... it basically assigns truth value to different capital letters). What is the name of this symbol and how can it be reproduced in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to answer such questions, for example:

> [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

You should have a look at: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) you can see, that this symbol is called `\mathscr{I}` and you need to include `\usepackage{ mathrsfs }` to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

And an alternative name is `\mathcal{I}` from the `calrsfs` package.